# Why is my directive not being seen in my AngularJS app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, gruntjs, angularjs-module

I have just created a directive in a file called `helloWorldz.js` file which looks like this :

```
'use strict';

angular.module('components')
  .directive('helloWorld', function () {
    return {
      restrict : 'E',
      template : '<span>Hello World</span>'
    };
});
```

my `app.js` file which contains my routes looks like this :

```
'use strict';

angular.module('mmApp', ['components'])
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/designs', {
        templateUrl: 'views/designs.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      })
      .when('/blog', {
        templateUrl: 'views/blog.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      })   
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  });
```

my controller `main.js` which is not done looks like this :

```
'use strict';

angular.module('mmApp', [])
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.designTiles = [
      { imageURL : "", title : "IMAGE" },
      { imageURL : "", title : "IMAGE" },
      { imageURL : "", title : "IMAGE" },
      { imageURL : "", title : "IMAGE" },
      { imageURL : "", title : "IMAGE" },
      { imageURL : "", title : "IMAGE" },
      { imageURL : "", title : "IMAGE" },
      { imageURL : "", title : "IMAGE" },
    ];
  });
```

Chrome Dev Tools tells me that `helloWorldz.js` is being successfully loaded. See below

[image]

I should mention that if I place my directive code in my `main.js` after my controller, and pass in `['components']` as the argument after `mmApp` I will see my directive code work. Here is the altered `main.js` controller :

```
'use strict';

angular.module('mmApp', ['components'])
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.designTiles = [
      { imageURL : "", title : "IMAGE" },
      { imageURL : "", title : "IMAGE" },
      { imageURL : "", title : "IMAGE" },
      { imageURL : "", title : "IMAGE" },
      { imageURL : "", title : "IMAGE" },
      { imageURL : "", title : "IMAGE" },
      { imageURL : "", title : "IMAGE" },
      { imageURL : "", title : "IMAGE" },
    ];
  });

angular.module('components', [])
  .directive('helloWorld', function () {
    return {
      restrict : 'E',
      template : '<span>Hello World</span>'
    }
});
```

How come `app.js` is not successfully calling in the `components` module which contains my `helloWorld` directive? Is this an possible issue with `app.js` not being able to connect to `helloWorldz.js`?

I should also mention that I am using grunt to compile everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the directive code is slightly different in the standalone version.  There is:

```
angular.module('components')
```

instead of

```
angular.module('components',[])
```

Fixing that (by adding the argument to the standalone version) should fix the problem. I think a bunch of people have run into this because the top comment on [AngularJS's module page](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module) is:

> This documentation should warn that "angular.module('myModule', [])"
>   always creates a new module, but "angular.module('myModule')" always
>   retrieves an existing reference.